# Record search with and without apostrophe

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

We want to get account record in Salesforce with soql or sos.

e.g suppose St. Patrick's account exists. Whenever we enter St. Patricks in input text box then system needs to return above record i.e St. Patrick's

Please let me know how to write either SOQL or SOQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to use SOSL if you need fuzzy matching:

```
Account[] accounts = (Account[])[FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name)][0];
```

Comment: @sfdcfox - In my tests this did not work for the OP's question. When searching for `St. Patricks` it did not return and account with the name `St. Patrick's`. Did you see different results

Comment: Eric, It working fine for me and tested with different data.

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking for is a fuzzy search and is not directly possible without a custom solution.

What you can do is require the user to enter the `'` in the name and in your code ensure you

```
string.escapeSingleQuotes({SearchTermInput})
```